# Android toolbar always centered title with icons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I want to center my title in toolbar. I have 4 cases to achieve, title should be always centered :

```
[<       short        ]
[< loooong_titleeee...]
[        short        ] 
[        short       +]
```

Below is my custom toolbar layout. 3 cases are perfectly, but the second one is not, it's cover back button. How should I change my layout to solve it? I tried many castlings in my layout, but every time something is wrong :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/iosBackgroundGray"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/left_text_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/right_text_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_36dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/iosDarkGray" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Set up your own custom Toolbar . Check out this for details. http://www.journaldev.com/9952/android-custom-action-bar-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Change the textView of title as follow:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:visibility="gone"
   android:layout_toEndOf="@id/left_buttons"
   android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/right_buttons" />
```

And the rightButtons layout as follow:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@id/right_buttons"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_gravity="end"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
```

Comment: It doesn't work in all cases except second one (with long title).

Comment: Ok, why it isn't working? Try adding: `android:layout_gravity="center" && android:gravity="center"` to the textView of title

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center" is not available in RelativeLayout. It's working now with android:gravity="center", but my title is still not centered properly, because of right or left visible buttons pushing my title to left or right. And it has like padding.

Comment: Sorry, didn't remember which one to use :p anyway, change the width to "match_parent" to the title, this should fix

Comment: No problem. match_parent also wouldn't work, I've tried. I'm done with this problem. Last solution is change rules of RelativeLayout dynamically. But I'm not fan of that kind of solutions :/

Comment: Can you post a picture of the layout with my changes? Not the code, but the results

Answer (score 0):

<<< but the second one is not, it's cover back button.

So ,If You are putting long title in  -> android:id="@+id/left_text_button"<- this Textview. and back button is ->  android:id="@+id/back_button".

Try Putting '**orientation=horizontal**' property in ->android:id="@+id/left_buttons" in this Linear Layout.

I hope this helps you.

**Edit:**

Well, what you are doing is very complicated. Try this solution,
In your all case there is back button, Title and right add button. So

For your back button , Use Android's back aerrow.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Drawable aerrow= ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_back);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(aerrow);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And Your xml,::

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#e2b5b5"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/root_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/add_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried this - It's not working in my first case. Title will be to right of back_button. I think it's situation without exit to resolve with layout and I leave it now, cuz I'm done.